# How to get the entries in a two-column nomenclature to align together?

Tags: two-column, nomencl

I would like to create a nomenclature with two columns. One column does not seem to align very well with the other. It seems as though this is happening due to insertion of small empty space by `\section*` command

[image]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}

% BEGIN_FOLD

    % nomencl commands
        
        \makenomenclature
        
        % remove the name of the nomenclature section
        \renewcommand{\nomname}{}
        
        % items seperation in the nomenclature
        \setlength{\nomitemsep}{1mm}
        
        % minimum width of 
        \renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}
    
    % Custom nomenclature groups
    \newlength{\heightNomgroupSep}
    \setlength{\heightNomgroupSep}{\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
        \item[%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}\bfseries Chemical Compounds}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{\vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}\bfseries Orginization Names}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{\vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}\bfseries Abbreviations}{}%
        ]%
    }

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}
    
\blindtext

\nomenclature{fertilizers}{\textarabic{اسمده}}%

\nomenclature{pesticides}{\textarabic{مبيدات حشرية}}%

\nomenclature{pollute}{\textarabic{يلوث}}%

\nomenclature{toxic}{\textarabic{سام}}%

\nomenclature{aquatic}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{monocultures}{\textarabic{الزراعة الأحادية}}%

\nomenclature{biodiversity}{\textarabic{التنوع الحيوي}}%

\nomenclature{landscapes}{\textarabic{المناظر الطبيعية}}%

\nomenclature{transportation}{\textarabic{النقل}}%

\nomenclature{artificial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{nutrient}{\textarabic{غذائي}}%

\nomenclature{fracking}{\textarabic{التكسير}}%

\nomenclature{spillage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{ocean}{\textarabic{محيط}}%

\nomenclature{dumping}{\textarabic{طرح}}%

\nomenclature{leakage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{algae}{\textarabic{طحالب}}%

\nomenclature{depletion}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{corrosive}{\textarabic{آكل (مسبب للتآكل)}}%

\nomenclature{carcinogen}{\textarabic{مسرطن}}%

\nomenclature{contaminated}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{hydraulic}{\textarabic{هيدروليكي}}%

\nomenclature{solvents}{\textarabic{المذيبات}}%

\nomenclature{endangered}{\textarabic{مهدد (بالانقراض)}}%

\nomenclature{extend}{\textarabic{يمتد}}%

\nomenclature{particulates}{\textarabic{الجسيمات}}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SO_{2}}$}{sulfur dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{NO_{x}}$}{nitrogen oxides}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CO_{2}}$}{carbon dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{N_{2}O}$}{nitrous oxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SF_{6}}$}{sulfur hexa-flouride}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{H_{2}SO_{4}}$}{sulphuric acid}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{Ar}$}{argon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CH_{4}}$}{methane}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{O_{3}}$}{ozone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaCO_{3}}$}{limestone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaO}$}{quicklime}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HC}$}{hydrobcarbon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HFCs}$}{hydroflourocarbons}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{PFCs}$}{perfluorocarbons}%

\nomenclature[O]{NOAA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للمحيطات والغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature[O]{NASA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للملاحة الجوية والفضاء}}%

\nomenclature[O]{IPCC}{\textarabic{الهيئة الحكومية الدولية المعنية بتغير المناخ}}%

\nomenclature[O]{EPA}{\textarabic{وكالة حماية البيئة}}%

\nomenclature[T]{GWP}{Global Warming Potential}%

\nomenclature[T]{CMM}{Coal Mine Methane}%

\nomenclature{smog}{\textarabic{ضباب دخاني}}%

\nomenclature{acidic}{\textarabic{حمضي}}%

\nomenclature{atmoshpere}{\textarabic{الغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature{global}{\textarabic{عالمي}}%

\nomenclature{manufacturing}{\textarabic{تصنيع}}%

\nomenclature{refinery}{\textarabic{مصفاة}}%

\nomenclature{industry}{\textarabic{صناعة}}%

\nomenclature{emission}{\textarabic{انبعاث}}%

\nomenclature{fossil}{\textarabic{احفوري}}%

\nomenclature{pollutant}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{dust}{\textarabic{غبار}}%

\nomenclature{streams}{\textarabic{تيارات}}%

\nomenclature{erode}{\textarabic{ينحت}}%

\nomenclature{trap}{\textarabic{يحبس}}%

\nomenclature{radiation}{\textarabic{اشعاع}}%

\nomenclature{deforestation}{\textarabic{التصحر}}%

\nomenclature{intensive}{\textarabic{كثيف}}%

\nomenclature{industrial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{respiration}{\textarabic{التعرق}}%

\nomenclature{quality}{\textarabic{جودة}}%

\nomenclature{degrade}{\textarabic{يتقادم}}%

\nomenclature{agricultural}{\textarabic{زراعي}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{expansion}{\textarabic{توسع}}%

\nomenclature{recreational}{\textarabic{ترفيهي}}%

\nomenclature{mining}{\textarabic{تنقيب}}%

\nomenclature{practice}{\textarabic{ممارسة}}%

\nomenclature{crop}{\textarabic{محصول}}%

\nomenclature{consumerism}{\textarabic{نمط استهلاكي}}%

\nomenclature{logging}{\textarabic{احتطاب}}%

\nomenclature{wildlife}{\textarabic{الحياة البرية}}%

\nomenclature{ecosystems}{\textarabic{الأنظمة الحيوية}}%

\nomenclature{offshore}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{drainage}{\textarabic{تصريف}}%

\nomenclature{infrastructure}{\textarabic{بنية تحتية}}%

\nomenclature{overexploitation}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{fallout}{\textarabic{تسرب (نووي)}}%

\nomenclature{peak}{\textarabic{قمة}}%

\nomenclature{ozone}{\textarabic{الأوزون}}%

\nomenclature{chlorofluorocarbon}{\textarabic{كلوروفلوروكربون}}%

\nomenclature{reliance}{\textarabic{اعتماد}}%

\nomenclature{nonrenewable}{\textarabic{غير متجدد}}%

\nomenclature{climate}{\textarabic{مناخ}}%

\nomenclature{composition}{\textarabic{تركيب}}%

\nomenclature{variability}{\textarabic{تغيرات}}%

\nomenclature{observe}{\textarabic{يراقب}}%

\nomenclature{anthropogenic}{\textarabic{بشري المصدر}}%

\nomenclature{continental}{\textarabic{قاري}}%

\nomenclature{drift}{\textarabic{انجراف}}%

\nomenclature{tilt}{\textarabic{ميلان}}%

\nomenclature{commet}{\textarabic{مذنب}}%

\nomenclature{meteorite}{\textarabic{نيزك}}%

\nomenclature{lifestyle}{\textarabic{نمط حياة}}%

\nomenclature{sufficient}{\textarabic{كافي}}%

\nomenclature{century}{\textarabic{قرن}}%

\nomenclature{irreversible}{\textarabic{لا يمكن عكسه}}%

\nomenclature{revolution}{\textarabic{ثورة}}%

\nomenclature{volatile}{\textarabic{متقلب}}%

\nomenclature{controversial}{\textarabic{مثير للجدل}}%

\nomenclature{multifaceted}{\textarabic{متعدد الأوجه}}%

\nomenclature{economic}{\textarabic{اقتصادي}}%

\nomenclature{sociological}{\textarabic{اجتماعي}}%

\nomenclature{psychological}{\textarabic{نفسي}}%

\nomenclature{consumption}{\textarabic{استهلاك}}%

\nomenclature{opinion}{\textarabic{رأي}}%

\nomenclature{complexity}{\textarabic{تعقيد}}%

\nomenclature{millenia}{\textarabic{ألفية}}%

\nomenclature{occur}{\textarabic{يحصل}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{noticeable}{\textarabic{يمكن ملاحظته}}%

\nomenclature{generation}{\textarabic{جيل}}%

\nomenclature{significant}{\textarabic{بارز}}%

\nomenclature{cycle}{\textarabic{دورة}}%

\nomenclature{wildfire}{\textarabic{حرائق الغابات}}%

\nomenclature{diffusion}{\textarabic{تشتيت}}%
    
% Two column nomenclature
\makeatletter
{
    
    \twocolumn
    
    \renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{}{}} % remove empty space
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{} % remove nomenclature name
        
    \printnomenclature
        
}
\makeatother
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redefinition of `\nomgroup` is a bit suboptimal. The rest should work.

Note, however, that you redefine all starred section macros to do nothing inside the group denoted by the curly brackets `{ ... }` at the end of your code if you define `\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{}{}}`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}

% BEGIN_FOLD
    % nomencl commands
    \makenomenclature
    
    % remove the name of the nomenclature section
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{}

    % items seperation in the nomenclature
    \setlength{\nomitemsep}{1mm}
    
    % minimum width of 
    \renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}
    
    % Custom nomenclature groups
    \newlength{\heightNomgroupSep}
    \setlength{\heightNomgroupSep}{\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Chemical Compounds}%
        }{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Orginization Names}%
        }{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Abbreviations}%
        }{}%
    }
% END_FOLD

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
\blindtext

\nomenclature{fertilizers}{\textarabic{اسمده}}%

\nomenclature{pesticides}{\textarabic{مبيدات حشرية}}%

\nomenclature{pollute}{\textarabic{يلوث}}%

\nomenclature{toxic}{\textarabic{سام}}%

\nomenclature{aquatic}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{monocultures}{\textarabic{الزراعة الأحادية}}%

\nomenclature{biodiversity}{\textarabic{التنوع الحيوي}}%

\nomenclature{landscapes}{\textarabic{المناظر الطبيعية}}%

\nomenclature{transportation}{\textarabic{النقل}}%

\nomenclature{artificial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{nutrient}{\textarabic{غذائي}}%

\nomenclature{fracking}{\textarabic{التكسير}}%

\nomenclature{spillage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{ocean}{\textarabic{محيط}}%

\nomenclature{dumping}{\textarabic{طرح}}%

\nomenclature{leakage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{algae}{\textarabic{طحالب}}%

\nomenclature{depletion}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{corrosive}{\textarabic{آكل (مسبب للتآكل)}}%

\nomenclature{carcinogen}{\textarabic{مسرطن}}%

\nomenclature{contaminated}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{hydraulic}{\textarabic{هيدروليكي}}%

\nomenclature{solvents}{\textarabic{المذيبات}}%

\nomenclature{endangered}{\textarabic{مهدد (بالانقراض)}}%

\nomenclature{extend}{\textarabic{يمتد}}%

\nomenclature{particulates}{\textarabic{الجسيمات}}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SO_{2}}$}{sulfur dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{NO_{x}}$}{nitrogen oxides}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CO_{2}}$}{carbon dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{N_{2}O}$}{nitrous oxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SF_{6}}$}{sulfur hexa-flouride}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{H_{2}SO_{4}}$}{sulphuric acid}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{Ar}$}{argon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CH_{4}}$}{methane}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{O_{3}}$}{ozone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaCO_{3}}$}{limestone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaO}$}{quicklime}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HC}$}{hydrobcarbon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HFCs}$}{hydroflourocarbons}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{PFCs}$}{perfluorocarbons}%

\nomenclature[O]{NOAA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للمحيطات والغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature[O]{NASA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للملاحة الجوية والفضاء}}%

\nomenclature[O]{IPCC}{\textarabic{الهيئة الحكومية الدولية المعنية بتغير المناخ}}%

\nomenclature[O]{EPA}{\textarabic{وكالة حماية البيئة}}%

\nomenclature[T]{GWP}{Global Warming Potential}%

\nomenclature[T]{CMM}{Coal Mine Methane}%

\nomenclature{smog}{\textarabic{ضباب دخاني}}%

\nomenclature{acidic}{\textarabic{حمضي}}%

\nomenclature{atmoshpere}{\textarabic{الغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature{global}{\textarabic{عالمي}}%

\nomenclature{manufacturing}{\textarabic{تصنيع}}%

\nomenclature{refinery}{\textarabic{مصفاة}}%

\nomenclature{industry}{\textarabic{صناعة}}%

\nomenclature{emission}{\textarabic{انبعاث}}%

\nomenclature{fossil}{\textarabic{احفوري}}%

\nomenclature{pollutant}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{dust}{\textarabic{غبار}}%

\nomenclature{streams}{\textarabic{تيارات}}%

\nomenclature{erode}{\textarabic{ينحت}}%

\nomenclature{trap}{\textarabic{يحبس}}%

\nomenclature{radiation}{\textarabic{اشعاع}}%

\nomenclature{deforestation}{\textarabic{التصحر}}%

\nomenclature{intensive}{\textarabic{كثيف}}%

\nomenclature{industrial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{respiration}{\textarabic{التعرق}}%

\nomenclature{quality}{\textarabic{جودة}}%

\nomenclature{degrade}{\textarabic{يتقادم}}%

\nomenclature{agricultural}{\textarabic{زراعي}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{expansion}{\textarabic{توسع}}%

\nomenclature{recreational}{\textarabic{ترفيهي}}%

\nomenclature{mining}{\textarabic{تنقيب}}%

\nomenclature{practice}{\textarabic{ممارسة}}%

\nomenclature{crop}{\textarabic{محصول}}%

\nomenclature{consumerism}{\textarabic{نمط استهلاكي}}%

\nomenclature{logging}{\textarabic{احتطاب}}%

\nomenclature{wildlife}{\textarabic{الحياة البرية}}%

\nomenclature{ecosystems}{\textarabic{الأنظمة الحيوية}}%

\nomenclature{offshore}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{drainage}{\textarabic{تصريف}}%

\nomenclature{infrastructure}{\textarabic{بنية تحتية}}%

\nomenclature{overexploitation}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{fallout}{\textarabic{تسرب (نووي)}}%

\nomenclature{peak}{\textarabic{قمة}}%

\nomenclature{ozone}{\textarabic{الأوزون}}%

\nomenclature{chlorofluorocarbon}{\textarabic{كلوروفلوروكربون}}%

\nomenclature{reliance}{\textarabic{اعتماد}}%

\nomenclature{nonrenewable}{\textarabic{غير متجدد}}%

\nomenclature{climate}{\textarabic{مناخ}}%

\nomenclature{composition}{\textarabic{تركيب}}%

\nomenclature{variability}{\textarabic{تغيرات}}%

\nomenclature{observe}{\textarabic{يراقب}}%

\nomenclature{anthropogenic}{\textarabic{بشري المصدر}}%

\nomenclature{continental}{\textarabic{قاري}}%

\nomenclature{drift}{\textarabic{انجراف}}%

\nomenclature{tilt}{\textarabic{ميلان}}%

\nomenclature{commet}{\textarabic{مذنب}}%

\nomenclature{meteorite}{\textarabic{نيزك}}%

\nomenclature{lifestyle}{\textarabic{نمط حياة}}%

\nomenclature{sufficient}{\textarabic{كافي}}%

\nomenclature{century}{\textarabic{قرن}}%

\nomenclature{irreversible}{\textarabic{لا يمكن عكسه}}%

\nomenclature{revolution}{\textarabic{ثورة}}%

\nomenclature{volatile}{\textarabic{متقلب}}%

\nomenclature{controversial}{\textarabic{مثير للجدل}}%

\nomenclature{multifaceted}{\textarabic{متعدد الأوجه}}%

\nomenclature{economic}{\textarabic{اقتصادي}}%

\nomenclature{sociological}{\textarabic{اجتماعي}}%

\nomenclature{psychological}{\textarabic{نفسي}}%

\nomenclature{consumption}{\textarabic{استهلاك}}%

\nomenclature{opinion}{\textarabic{رأي}}%

\nomenclature{complexity}{\textarabic{تعقيد}}%

\nomenclature{millenia}{\textarabic{ألفية}}%

\nomenclature{occur}{\textarabic{يحصل}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{noticeable}{\textarabic{يمكن ملاحظته}}%

\nomenclature{generation}{\textarabic{جيل}}%

\nomenclature{significant}{\textarabic{بارز}}%

\nomenclature{cycle}{\textarabic{دورة}}%

\nomenclature{wildfire}{\textarabic{حرائق الغابات}}%

\nomenclature{diffusion}{\textarabic{تشتيت}}%
    
% Two column nomenclature

{
    \twocolumn
    
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{}{}} % remove empty space
    \makeatother

    \printnomenclature
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed Jasper Habicht's redefinition of `\nomgroup`.

If you like, you can (ab?)use nomencl's `\nompreamble`/`\nompostamble` for beginning/ending a `multicols`-environment of the `multicol`-package.

This way you don't need to start a new page for twocolumn-layout.

```latex
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
    \makenomenclature
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\nomenclature{fertilizers}{\textarabic{اسمده}}%

\nomenclature{pesticides}{\textarabic{مبيدات حشرية}}%

\nomenclature{pollute}{\textarabic{يلوث}}%

\nomenclature{toxic}{\textarabic{سام}}%

\nomenclature{aquatic}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{monocultures}{\textarabic{الزراعة الأحادية}}%

\nomenclature{biodiversity}{\textarabic{التنوع الحيوي}}%

\nomenclature{landscapes}{\textarabic{المناظر الطبيعية}}%

\nomenclature{transportation}{\textarabic{النقل}}%

\nomenclature{artificial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{nutrient}{\textarabic{غذائي}}%

\nomenclature{fracking}{\textarabic{التكسير}}%

\nomenclature{spillage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{ocean}{\textarabic{محيط}}%

\nomenclature{dumping}{\textarabic{طرح}}%

\nomenclature{leakage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{algae}{\textarabic{طحالب}}%

\nomenclature{depletion}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{corrosive}{\textarabic{آكل (مسبب للتآكل)}}%

\nomenclature{carcinogen}{\textarabic{مسرطن}}%

\nomenclature{contaminated}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{hydraulic}{\textarabic{هيدروليكي}}%

\nomenclature{solvents}{\textarabic{المذيبات}}%

\nomenclature{endangered}{\textarabic{مهدد (بالانقراض)}}%

\nomenclature{extend}{\textarabic{يمتد}}%

\nomenclature{particulates}{\textarabic{الجسيمات}}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SO_{2}}$}{sulfur dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{NO_{x}}$}{nitrogen oxides}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CO_{2}}$}{carbon dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{N_{2}O}$}{nitrous oxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SF_{6}}$}{sulfur hexa-flouride}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{H_{2}SO_{4}}$}{sulphuric acid}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{Ar}$}{argon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CH_{4}}$}{methane}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{O_{3}}$}{ozone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaCO_{3}}$}{limestone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaO}$}{quicklime}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HC}$}{hydrobcarbon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HFCs}$}{hydroflourocarbons}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{PFCs}$}{perfluorocarbons}%

\nomenclature[O]{NOAA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للمحيطات والغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature[O]{NASA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للملاحة الجوية والفضاء}}%

\nomenclature[O]{IPCC}{\textarabic{الهيئة الحكومية الدولية المعنية بتغير المناخ}}%

\nomenclature[O]{EPA}{\textarabic{وكالة حماية البيئة}}%

\nomenclature[T]{GWP}{Global Warming Potential}%

\nomenclature[T]{CMM}{Coal Mine Methane}%

\nomenclature{smog}{\textarabic{ضباب دخاني}}%

\nomenclature{acidic}{\textarabic{حمضي}}%

\nomenclature{atmoshpere}{\textarabic{الغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature{global}{\textarabic{عالمي}}%

\nomenclature{manufacturing}{\textarabic{تصنيع}}%

\nomenclature{refinery}{\textarabic{مصفاة}}%

\nomenclature{industry}{\textarabic{صناعة}}%

\nomenclature{emission}{\textarabic{انبعاث}}%

\nomenclature{fossil}{\textarabic{احفوري}}%

\nomenclature{pollutant}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{dust}{\textarabic{غبار}}%

\nomenclature{streams}{\textarabic{تيارات}}%

\nomenclature{erode}{\textarabic{ينحت}}%

\nomenclature{trap}{\textarabic{يحبس}}%

\nomenclature{radiation}{\textarabic{اشعاع}}%

\nomenclature{deforestation}{\textarabic{التصحر}}%

\nomenclature{intensive}{\textarabic{كثيف}}%

\nomenclature{industrial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{respiration}{\textarabic{التعرق}}%

\nomenclature{quality}{\textarabic{جودة}}%

\nomenclature{degrade}{\textarabic{يتقادم}}%

\nomenclature{agricultural}{\textarabic{زراعي}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{expansion}{\textarabic{توسع}}%

\nomenclature{recreational}{\textarabic{ترفيهي}}%

\nomenclature{mining}{\textarabic{تنقيب}}%

\nomenclature{practice}{\textarabic{ممارسة}}%

\nomenclature{crop}{\textarabic{محصول}}%

\nomenclature{consumerism}{\textarabic{نمط استهلاكي}}%

\nomenclature{logging}{\textarabic{احتطاب}}%

\nomenclature{wildlife}{\textarabic{الحياة البرية}}%

\nomenclature{ecosystems}{\textarabic{الأنظمة الحيوية}}%

\nomenclature{offshore}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{drainage}{\textarabic{تصريف}}%

\nomenclature{infrastructure}{\textarabic{بنية تحتية}}%

\nomenclature{overexploitation}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{fallout}{\textarabic{تسرب (نووي)}}%

\nomenclature{peak}{\textarabic{قمة}}%

\nomenclature{ozone}{\textarabic{الأوزون}}%

\nomenclature{chlorofluorocarbon}{\textarabic{كلوروفلوروكربون}}%

\nomenclature{reliance}{\textarabic{اعتماد}}%

\nomenclature{nonrenewable}{\textarabic{غير متجدد}}%

\nomenclature{climate}{\textarabic{مناخ}}%

\nomenclature{composition}{\textarabic{تركيب}}%

\nomenclature{variability}{\textarabic{تغيرات}}%

\nomenclature{observe}{\textarabic{يراقب}}%

\nomenclature{anthropogenic}{\textarabic{بشري المصدر}}%

\nomenclature{continental}{\textarabic{قاري}}%

\nomenclature{drift}{\textarabic{انجراف}}%

\nomenclature{tilt}{\textarabic{ميلان}}%

\nomenclature{commet}{\textarabic{مذنب}}%

\nomenclature{meteorite}{\textarabic{نيزك}}%

\nomenclature{lifestyle}{\textarabic{نمط حياة}}%

\nomenclature{sufficient}{\textarabic{كافي}}%

\nomenclature{century}{\textarabic{قرن}}%

\nomenclature{irreversible}{\textarabic{لا يمكن عكسه}}%

\nomenclature{revolution}{\textarabic{ثورة}}%

\nomenclature{volatile}{\textarabic{متقلب}}%

\nomenclature{controversial}{\textarabic{مثير للجدل}}%

\nomenclature{multifaceted}{\textarabic{متعدد الأوجه}}%

\nomenclature{economic}{\textarabic{اقتصادي}}%

\nomenclature{sociological}{\textarabic{اجتماعي}}%

\nomenclature{psychological}{\textarabic{نفسي}}%

\nomenclature{consumption}{\textarabic{استهلاك}}%

\nomenclature{opinion}{\textarabic{رأي}}%

\nomenclature{complexity}{\textarabic{تعقيد}}%

\nomenclature{millenia}{\textarabic{ألفية}}%

\nomenclature{occur}{\textarabic{يحصل}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{noticeable}{\textarabic{يمكن ملاحظته}}%

\nomenclature{generation}{\textarabic{جيل}}%

\nomenclature{significant}{\textarabic{بارز}}%

\nomenclature{cycle}{\textarabic{دورة}}%

\nomenclature{wildfire}{\textarabic{حرائق الغابات}}%

\nomenclature{diffusion}{\textarabic{تشتيت}}%

% Two column nomenclature
{
    % remove the name of the nomenclature section
    %\renewcommand{\nomname}{}

    % items seperation in the nomenclature
    % \setlength acts resticted to the current scope
    \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

    % Custom nomenclature groups
    \newcommand*\heightNomgroupSep{}
    \edef\heightNomgroupSep{\the\baselineskip}
    % Allocating another register is probably not needed.
    % \newlength{\heightNomgroupSep}
    % \setlength{\heightNomgroupSep}{\baselineskip}

    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Chemical Compounds}%
        }{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Organization Names}%
        }{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Abbreviations}%
        }{}%
    }

    \def\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}%
    \def\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}%

    % minimum width of 
    % \renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}
    \printnomenclature[2.5cm]%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't wish a heading with the nomenclature, I suggest redefining `\thenomenclature`, the command underlying the `thenomenclature`-environment, not to print headings and not to add entries to the table of contents and not to change the page-headings—with the example below I assume **nomencl 2020/12/29 v5.5** is in use—redefining the `thenomenclature`-environment is suggested in section ["2.8.1 Formatting the Nomenclature"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf#subsubsection.2.8.1) of the  package documentation of the nomencl package:

> If you don’t like the format of the nomenclature at all, you will have
> to redefine the `thenomenclature` environment. Maybe a look at the
> documented code of nomencl will help.

If you just redefine `\nomname` to deliver no tokens, the commands for creating a section-heading for the nomenclature will be carried out with an empty argument, probably yielding

- vertical space where a heading would be and where the empty heading is vertically separated from the following text,
- changes of page-headers and
- empty entries via `\addcontentsline` in the table of contents and
- , in case hyperref is in use, bookmarks with no text.

```latex
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
    \makenomenclature
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\nomenclature{fertilizers}{\textarabic{اسمده}}%

\nomenclature{pesticides}{\textarabic{مبيدات حشرية}}%

\nomenclature{pollute}{\textarabic{يلوث}}%

\nomenclature{toxic}{\textarabic{سام}}%

\nomenclature{aquatic}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{monocultures}{\textarabic{الزراعة الأحادية}}%

\nomenclature{biodiversity}{\textarabic{التنوع الحيوي}}%

\nomenclature{landscapes}{\textarabic{المناظر الطبيعية}}%

\nomenclature{transportation}{\textarabic{النقل}}%

\nomenclature{artificial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{nutrient}{\textarabic{غذائي}}%

\nomenclature{fracking}{\textarabic{التكسير}}%

\nomenclature{spillage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{ocean}{\textarabic{محيط}}%

\nomenclature{dumping}{\textarabic{طرح}}%

\nomenclature{leakage}{\textarabic{تسرب}}%

\nomenclature{algae}{\textarabic{طحالب}}%

\nomenclature{depletion}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{corrosive}{\textarabic{آكل (مسبب للتآكل)}}%

\nomenclature{carcinogen}{\textarabic{مسرطن}}%

\nomenclature{contaminated}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{hydraulic}{\textarabic{هيدروليكي}}%

\nomenclature{solvents}{\textarabic{المذيبات}}%

\nomenclature{endangered}{\textarabic{مهدد (بالانقراض)}}%

\nomenclature{extend}{\textarabic{يمتد}}%

\nomenclature{particulates}{\textarabic{الجسيمات}}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SO_{2}}$}{sulfur dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{NO_{x}}$}{nitrogen oxides}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CO_{2}}$}{carbon dioxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{N_{2}O}$}{nitrous oxide}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{SF_{6}}$}{sulfur hexa-flouride}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{H_{2}SO_{4}}$}{sulphuric acid}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{Ar}$}{argon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CH_{4}}$}{methane}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{O_{3}}$}{ozone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaCO_{3}}$}{limestone}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{CaO}$}{quicklime}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HC}$}{hydrobcarbon}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{HFCs}$}{hydroflourocarbons}%

\nomenclature[C]{$\mathrm{PFCs}$}{perfluorocarbons}%

\nomenclature[O]{NOAA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للمحيطات والغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature[O]{NASA}{\textarabic{الإدارة الوطنية للملاحة الجوية والفضاء}}%

\nomenclature[O]{IPCC}{\textarabic{الهيئة الحكومية الدولية المعنية بتغير المناخ}}%

\nomenclature[O]{EPA}{\textarabic{وكالة حماية البيئة}}%

\nomenclature[T]{GWP}{Global Warming Potential}%

\nomenclature[T]{CMM}{Coal Mine Methane}%

\nomenclature{smog}{\textarabic{ضباب دخاني}}%

\nomenclature{acidic}{\textarabic{حمضي}}%

\nomenclature{atmoshpere}{\textarabic{الغلاف الجوي}}%

\nomenclature{global}{\textarabic{عالمي}}%

\nomenclature{manufacturing}{\textarabic{تصنيع}}%

\nomenclature{refinery}{\textarabic{مصفاة}}%

\nomenclature{industry}{\textarabic{صناعة}}%

\nomenclature{emission}{\textarabic{انبعاث}}%

\nomenclature{fossil}{\textarabic{احفوري}}%

\nomenclature{pollutant}{\textarabic{ملوث}}%

\nomenclature{dust}{\textarabic{غبار}}%

\nomenclature{streams}{\textarabic{تيارات}}%

\nomenclature{erode}{\textarabic{ينحت}}%

\nomenclature{trap}{\textarabic{يحبس}}%

\nomenclature{radiation}{\textarabic{اشعاع}}%

\nomenclature{deforestation}{\textarabic{التصحر}}%

\nomenclature{intensive}{\textarabic{كثيف}}%

\nomenclature{industrial}{\textarabic{صناعي}}%

\nomenclature{respiration}{\textarabic{التعرق}}%

\nomenclature{quality}{\textarabic{جودة}}%

\nomenclature{degrade}{\textarabic{يتقادم}}%

\nomenclature{agricultural}{\textarabic{زراعي}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{expansion}{\textarabic{توسع}}%

\nomenclature{recreational}{\textarabic{ترفيهي}}%

\nomenclature{mining}{\textarabic{تنقيب}}%

\nomenclature{practice}{\textarabic{ممارسة}}%

\nomenclature{crop}{\textarabic{محصول}}%

\nomenclature{consumerism}{\textarabic{نمط استهلاكي}}%

\nomenclature{logging}{\textarabic{احتطاب}}%

\nomenclature{wildlife}{\textarabic{الحياة البرية}}%

\nomenclature{ecosystems}{\textarabic{الأنظمة الحيوية}}%

\nomenclature{offshore}{\textarabic{بحري}}%

\nomenclature{drainage}{\textarabic{تصريف}}%

\nomenclature{infrastructure}{\textarabic{بنية تحتية}}%

\nomenclature{overexploitation}{\textarabic{استنزاف}}%

\nomenclature{fallout}{\textarabic{تسرب (نووي)}}%

\nomenclature{peak}{\textarabic{قمة}}%

\nomenclature{ozone}{\textarabic{الأوزون}}%

\nomenclature{chlorofluorocarbon}{\textarabic{كلوروفلوروكربون}}%

\nomenclature{reliance}{\textarabic{اعتماد}}%

\nomenclature{nonrenewable}{\textarabic{غير متجدد}}%

\nomenclature{climate}{\textarabic{مناخ}}%

\nomenclature{composition}{\textarabic{تركيب}}%

\nomenclature{variability}{\textarabic{تغيرات}}%

\nomenclature{observe}{\textarabic{يراقب}}%

\nomenclature{anthropogenic}{\textarabic{بشري المصدر}}%

\nomenclature{continental}{\textarabic{قاري}}%

\nomenclature{drift}{\textarabic{انجراف}}%

\nomenclature{tilt}{\textarabic{ميلان}}%

\nomenclature{commet}{\textarabic{مذنب}}%

\nomenclature{meteorite}{\textarabic{نيزك}}%

\nomenclature{lifestyle}{\textarabic{نمط حياة}}%

\nomenclature{sufficient}{\textarabic{كافي}}%

\nomenclature{century}{\textarabic{قرن}}%

\nomenclature{irreversible}{\textarabic{لا يمكن عكسه}}%

\nomenclature{revolution}{\textarabic{ثورة}}%

\nomenclature{volatile}{\textarabic{متقلب}}%

\nomenclature{controversial}{\textarabic{مثير للجدل}}%

\nomenclature{multifaceted}{\textarabic{متعدد الأوجه}}%

\nomenclature{economic}{\textarabic{اقتصادي}}%

\nomenclature{sociological}{\textarabic{اجتماعي}}%

\nomenclature{psychological}{\textarabic{نفسي}}%

\nomenclature{consumption}{\textarabic{استهلاك}}%

\nomenclature{opinion}{\textarabic{رأي}}%

\nomenclature{complexity}{\textarabic{تعقيد}}%

\nomenclature{millenia}{\textarabic{ألفية}}%

\nomenclature{occur}{\textarabic{يحصل}}%

\nomenclature{urban}{\textarabic{حضري}}%

\nomenclature{noticeable}{\textarabic{يمكن ملاحظته}}%

\nomenclature{generation}{\textarabic{جيل}}%

\nomenclature{significant}{\textarabic{بارز}}%

\nomenclature{cycle}{\textarabic{دورة}}%

\nomenclature{wildfire}{\textarabic{حرائق الغابات}}%

\nomenclature{diffusion}{\textarabic{تشتيت}}%

% Two column nomenclature
{
    % remove the name of the nomenclature section
    %\renewcommand{\nomname}{}

    % Redefine thenomenclature-environment not to print headings:
    \makeatletter
    \def\thenomenclature{%
      \providecommand*{\listofnlsname}{\nomname}%
      %%\if@nomencl@tocbasic
      %%  \let\list@fname\listofnlsname
      %%  \def\@currext{nls}%
      %%  \tocbasic@listhead{\list@fname}%
      %%\else
      %%  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
      %%  {
      %%    \section*{\nomname}
      %%    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi
      %%  }%
      %%  {
      %%    \chapter*{\nomname}
      %%    \@mkboth{\nomname}{\nomname}%
      %%    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi
      %%  }%
      %%\fi
      \nompreamble
        \if@nomentbl
        \let\itemOrig=\item
        \def\item{\gdef\item{\\}}%
        \expandafter\longtable\expandafter{\@nomtableformat}%
      \else
        \list{}{%
        \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \itemsep\nomitemsep
        \let\makelabel\nomlabel}%
      \fi
    }
    \makeatother

    % items seperation in the nomenclature
    % \setlength acts resticted to the current scope
    \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

    % Custom nomenclature groups
    \newcommand*\heightNomgroupSep{}
    \edef\heightNomgroupSep{\the\baselineskip}
    % Allocating another register is probably not needed.
    % \newlength{\heightNomgroupSep}
    % \setlength{\heightNomgroupSep}{\baselineskip}

    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Chemical Compounds}%
        }{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Organization Names}%
        }{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
            \vspace{\heightNomgroupSep}%
            \item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
            \textbf{Abbreviations}%
        }{}%
    }

    \def\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}%
    \def\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}%

    % minimum width of 
    % \renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}
    \printnomenclature[2.5cm]%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]